# Wordpress is stripping the Alt tag's quote marks from images where Alt is not set, but leaving the word 'alt' creating problems for ADA compliance

Tags: images

How do I get around this? For ADA compliance I specifically need `alt=""` on some of my images in a wordpress site, however wordpress is stripping the Alt tag's quote marks from images where Alt is not set, and just leaving the word 'alt' without the quotation marks. How do I make sure the Alt tags are left intact with their quote marks? I just need it to say `alt=""` instead of `alt`. ! :D

Comment: At first glance I don't think wp_get_attachment_image would do that: it doesn't generate empty/minimized attributes like that. Where are you getting the <img> HTML tag from?

Comment: We are using Visual Composer, maybe it's something to do with VC?

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue and while the dev tools show it as `alt` the source code shows `alt=""`, so WordPress is not stripping the quotes, but even if it was, they're equivalent. Eitherway this is not something WordPress would do

Comment: @TomJNowell. You've answered my question. Thank you.  I was looking through dev tools elements and seeing empty ALT tags without the quotes, thinking that was the source of the error on the ADA compliance report. I wonder why Dev Tools does that?

Comment: because the dev tools do not display the HTML markup, they display the DOM

Comment: @TomJNowell Why would the DOM not include HTML markup that's part of the DOM?

Comment: that's an incorrect description of how the DOM works. The DOM is a data structure that is the working model for the current page. HTML can be parsed into a DOM but that doesn't mean the HTML is a DOM, or that a DOM contains HTML markup. This is especially obvious if you try to write broken HTML and load it in a browser, e.g. `<img> <strong><div>text</div></strong></img>`. The DOM itself does not contain quotes or angle brackets, those are created by the browser for display to you in a user interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to replicate your issue and while the dev tools show it as `alt` the source code shows `alt=""`, so WordPress is not stripping the quotes, it's just the dev tools being concise. But even if it was, they're equivalent so `alt` and `alt=""` are the same.

As for why the dev tools display `alt`, it's because the dev tools don't display the HTML, they display the DOM